# SOLR stops indexing in Alfresco 4.0.2

Tags: solr, indexing, alfresco

I have a problem with SOLR indexing in Alfresco. It is not possible to index newly created content. There are not exceptions in log file.

I enabled debuging for *org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker* and found that from Transaction id is not increased. It looks like infinity loop.

```
    INFO: Scanning transactions ...
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker        trackTransactions
    INFO: .... from Transaction [id=335, commitTimeMs=1345501423910, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... from Transaction [id=335, commitTimeMs=1345501423910, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... to Transaction [id=342, commitTimeMs=1345504959777, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... to Transaction [id=342, commitTimeMs=1345504959777, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: Scanning transactions ...
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: Scanning transactions ...
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... from Transaction [id=335, commitTimeMs=1345501423910, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... from Transaction [id=335, commitTimeMs=1345501423910, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... to Transaction [id=342, commitTimeMs=1345504959777, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
    INFO: .... to Transaction [id=342, commitTimeMs=1345504959777, updates=0, deletes=0]
    Aug 22, 2012 9:36:09 AM org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MultiThreadedCoreTracker trackTransactions
```

I tried to fix this calling admin/cores?action=FIX (to fix problems in SOLR) but it does not help and I can not see any exceptions in log.

Is there any other way to start indexing?

EDIT: I solved this problem upgrading to Alfresco 4.0.29 and rebuild indexes. I think I saw similar issue on Alfresco Jira but I can not find it. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to Alfresco using JConsole.

Navigate to MBeans tab.

Under Alfresco > SolrIndexes > alfresco > Operations , you will find a method checkAndFixIndex. Invoke it to fix your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add in alfresco.global.properties the following option:
**index.tracking.disableInTransactionIndexing=false**?